# Symfony 2 try to get wrong route in prod environment

Tags: symfony, routes

Hello :) I just tried to open my application in prod environment and assetic is was not working well.
I looked on my app/cache/prod.log

i changed localhost by *** to avoid problems editing my question

So i see that symfony try to get a completly wrong route :

```
request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /" (from "http://localhost/aceProject/api/Symfony/")" at D:\logiciel\wamp\www\pitchan.fr\api\Symfony\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener.php line 145 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for \"GET /\" (from \"http://localhost/aceProject/api/Symfony/\") at D:\\logiciel\\wamp\\www\\pitchan.fr\\api\\Symfony\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener.php:145, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException:  at D:\\logiciel\\wamp\\www\\pitchan.fr\\api\\Symfony\\app\\cache\\prod\\appProdUrlMatcher.php:32)"} []
```

How can i change this route and tell to symfony a good path ? 
I see that when i load my application, a symfony folder is created in this same path, how is it possible ? my symfony folder i in :

```
http://***/symfony and not http://***/aceProject/api/Symfony/
```

If someone know how to fix that it would be awesome :)

Thanks a lot in advance by !!

**Edit :** I also tried

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

I get an error :

```
[RuntimeException]
Unable to write in the "D:/logiciel/wamp/www/pitchan.fr/api/symfony/app/cacche/prod" directory
```

This path is totally wrong ... i really dont understand what happened here

Best regards,
CUETO Vincent

Comment: Have you defined a route for the site root (`/`)?

Comment: Have you changed something in app_dev.php an not in app.php?

Comment: Hi :) the only thing i changed in app.php is `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` with the boolean set to true instead of false. In app_dev.php nothing changed

Comment: Hi @A.L in my app/config/routing.yml all my prefix are sets to `/`

Comment: do you have problems only with assetic ? If so you have probably a rewrite rule on the whole website, when you need to add exceptions for js, css and images

Comment: Hi @oligan You are right there is a assetic folder missing in my prod env but he is set in the wrong path .. How can i fix this ?

Comment: My answer is in the case where none of your asssetic resources work in prod , but here... what do you mean by set in the wrong path

Comment: The result of my prod is that no one of my css and javascript works and by wrong path i mean my project is not `D:/logiciel/wamp/www/pitchan.fr/api/symfony/` but `D:/logiciel/wamp/www/symfony/` take a look to my edit :s its strange

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem was that my kernel cache pointed to a wrong location so .. i overrided it :

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return $this->rootDir.'/my_cache/'.$this->environment;
}
```

Thanks for the help all